# What does it mean when log mean temperature difference is inconsistent with the conservation of energy?

Tags: thermodynamics

Heat Exchanger

The value of heat transfer rate calculated from the conservation of energy is lower than the value calculated from log mean temperature difference equation.

There is a shell loss of the heat exchanger therefore conservation of energy is untrue?

Comment: I don't really understand what you're asking but let me reassure you that energy is still conserved.